# Every positive integers of the form $4k+1$ can be factored into Hilbert primes

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How can I show that every positive integer of the form $4k+1$ can be factored into Hilbert primes?

A Hilbert prime is defined as a positive integer of the form $4k+1$ without a smaller factor of this form.

Comment: A Hilbert prime is defined as a positive integer of the form $4k+1$ without a smaller factor of this form!

Answer (score 0):

> **Definition:** $x\in\mathbb{N}$ is a Hilbert Prime if $x\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ and there does not exists a $y<x$ such that $y\equiv
>  1\pmod{4}$ and $y|x$.

Let $\alpha=4k+1$. If $\alpha$ is not a Hilbert Prime, then by definition there exists a $\beta_0$ such that $\beta_0$ is a of the form $4k_0+1$ and $\beta_0|\alpha$. If $\beta_0$ is a Hilbert Prime we are done, otherwise it is divisible by some $\beta_1$ such that $\beta_1=4k_1+1$. If iterating this never terminates, then we have an infinite decreasing sequence of natural numbers, which is impossible, so it must terminate in some $\beta'$. $\beta'$ is a Hilbert Prime by definition and by transitivity of divides, $\beta'|\alpha$.

If $\alpha$ is a Hilbert Prime, then $\alpha|\alpha$ and we are done!