# Algebraic expression of Prime of form $4k-1$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, field-theory

Every prime of the form $4k+1$ can be written as an algebraic expresion of  sum of two squares.

**Question:**
If $p=4k-1 $, can it be written as a sum of some powers? (algebraic exprssion like $p= y^3+ (-z^9)+7$, this is an exmple to give the idea).

The post is motivated by this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1762950/every-positive-integers-of-the-form-4k1-can-be-factored-into-hilbert-primes).

Comment: Every positive integer is the sum of *four* squares.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *only*?

Comment: @Jim: What do you mean by "only"? The property described in your question is true **not only** for $4k+1$ primes.

Comment: Maybe you like this one better they are of the form $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 +1$, and the other odd primes are not.

Comment: @quid ,  I withdraw the word $only$, what i tried to mean was if a prime is of form $4k-1$ then we can write it something like $4k+1$, what you said is true for all positive integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in this aspect is: No
In the language of algebraic number theory (class field theory), we can view this question in an equivalat question as follows:
the prime number p splits/ramifies iff p is not congruent to 3 modulue 4 or 
the prime number p remains inert iff p is congruent to 3 modulue 4.

---

we can suppose the main problem in general as follows: (without details and in non-exaxt sence)
given a subset of Z, with the good situation on it, then there exist a unique field extension such that almost surely (almost everry where) the given set is equal to the set of spliting integers.
***** Results from class field theory are very deep.
I have been read class field theory long time ago, and may be there is some mistake in what I say, but I am sure in this view the answer is no.

Answer (score 4):

This won't answer your question but, I hope, will help putting the problem in context.

Fix a quadratic extension $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{d})\supset\Bbb Q$. A prime number $p$ is said to *split* in $K$ if the ideal $p{\cal O}_K$ decomposes as the product of two different prime ideals in ${\cal O}_K$.

Here ${\cal O}_K\subset K$ is the ring of integers in $K$, i.e. the ring of all elements in $K$ that are roots of monic polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb Z$. Concretely, one knows that ${\cal O}_K=\Bbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$ if $\Bbb Z\ni d\equiv 2$ or $3\bmod 4$ and ${\cal O}_K=\Bbb Z[\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}2]$ if $\Bbb Z\ni d\equiv1\bmod 4$ (one readily realizes that these cover all possible quadratic extensions $K$).

It is a consequence of the existence of a [reciprocity law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocity_law), which in the quadratic case boils down to [Gauss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) that the set of primes that split in $K$ are in an arithmetic sequence.

The arithmetic sequence $4k+1$ that shows up when you want to write primes as a sum of two squares characterizes the primes that split in the extension $K=\Bbb Q(i)$ ($i^2=-1$) because of some arithmetic fact about the latter (namely, that the [class number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_class_group) of $K$ is $1$).

The moral is that among the primes of the form $4k+3$ you can find suitable subsequences of primes (in fact, arithmetic subsequences which means defined by congruence conditions) that can be written in the form $x^2-dy^2$ for suitable $d\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Thanks that was informative. What kind of restriction can make $d$ of the form $4k - 1$ ? (background: I get gaussian integer).

Comment: Certainly the above works for at least all $d$ such that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{d})$ has class number $1$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_number_fields_with_class_number_one

Answer (score 2):

If $p \equiv 3 \pmod 8,$ we can get integers in
$$  p = x^2 + 2 y^2 $$

If $p \equiv 7 \pmod 8,$ we can get integers in
$$  p = x^2 - 2 y^2 $$

Answer (score 1):

All number not of the form $4^n(8m+7)$ is a sum of three squares and reciprocally (Legendre) so for all prime $p$ of this form  the equation $$x^2+y^2+z^2=p$$ has no solution. This occurs for infinitely many primes of the form $p=4n-1$ because $4k-1\equiv4^n(8m+7)\pmod 4$ for $n=0$.

Examples of these primes are $$p=7,23,31,47,71,79,103,199,223,239,.......$$

It follows that all prime, not in this (infinite) list are a sum of three squares.

On the other hand all natural integer is a sum of four squares (Lagrange) which can be extended to more squares.